# How I can show logs in real time from different projects to a DashBoard?

Tags: c#, api, rest, model-view-controller

What is the best choice that I can make to show logs in real time from 4 different projects to a DashBoard? I have 4 projects and a Dashboard for Admin there is possible to view, manage every bug, event from projects. All projects communicate with Dashboard with rest API and I don't want to overload projects with  simple rest api request to parse a string. I think that I can make a txt file there will be logs or I can save in memory and to parse the string, and after to send to Dashboard. I want to optimize the speed of working projects.

Comment: Are you using a database? Writing error logs to db and read it from the dashboard is probably the best option for your case.

Comment: if(realtime == signalr) :D you this always returns true